# what is the difference between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and -rpath

Tags: g++, linker-scripts

When linking libraries, -rpath is used to pass the address of dynamic libraries to ld. My question is if I set the address in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, do I still need -rpath flag in my linking 
process?

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you don't need it and in fact it's preferable to not have the library search path encoded in the executable (the `-rpath` option encodes the path in the binary, either as `DT_RPATH` or `DR_RUNPATH`)

PS. My own general approach is to link executables **with** the `--rpath` option, while they are in build tree and depend on other libraries in the build tree, to facilitate debugging, but upon installation (`make install`, building packages) to re-link **without** `--rpath` option and leave the task of finding the shared libraries to the appropriate dynamic linker configuration (e.g. `ld.so.conf`) of the target platform.

Comment: How do you accomplish this using automake?