# Makefile cannot find shared library

Tags: c++, makefile, shared-libraries

I have this folder structure:

```
Project_folder
Project_folder/Ml.app (folder)
Project_folder/Ml.lib (folder)
```

In the folder Ml.lib I've created a shared library named ml.so
Now I want to link to the client application inside the Ml.app folder.
Here's my makefile:

```
LIBS = -L ../Ml.lib -l ml
INCLUDES = ../Ml.lib
CXXLAGS = -Wall -I$(INCLUDES)
OBJFILES = main.o
TARGET   = mltest
all: $(TARGET)
$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
        $(CXX) $(CXXLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
        
clean:
        rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

but when I try to build it I get

> g++ -Wall -I../Ml.lib   -o mltest main.o -L ../Ml.lib -l ml
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lml collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status make: *** [Makefile:8: mltest] Error 1

Comment: -L is for directories, -l is for libraries. Use `-L ..` .

Comment: @Anonymous1847 I know it but could you tell me how I should change my script?

Comment: `-l ml` is wrong, should not have a space in there.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. doesn't work anyway

Comment: Also `-lml` looks for a file named `libml.so` and not `ml.so`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. that's it! Finally compiled it! The only thing is I have to export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/shared/lib/directory:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH if I want the client application to find the library. Any other option for that (for example like on Windows I can put the library in the same directory with client application)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617137/what-is-the-difference-between-ld-library-path-and-rpath

Answer (score 1):

The option `-L` specifies an additional search directory for libraries. `-l` looks for an additonal library. Use:

```
LIBS = -L .. -l Ml
```

Comment: I thnk it should be ml, not Ml. Another thing is that *ml.so* is not in the Project_folder, but in Project_folder/Ml.lib folder

Comment: @amplifier Ml.lib is a directory? Huh. I thought it was the shared library itself, given the .lib extension suffix. In fact that might be confusing the linker, try renaming the directory.

Comment: Renamed it (removed dot), still no luck